# OpenCL only on AMD: CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE

Tags: opencl, amd-app

I have a kernel that runs on all platforms that I have access to, but AMD app SDK 3.0 with intel.
The platform is: `OpenCL.Device(Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz on AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing`

The MWE (sorry it's in Julia, but calls should be almost the same as in C):

```
using OpenCL
test_source = "
struct __attribute__((packed)) Test{
    float3 f1;
    int f2;
    float f3;
};
__kernel void structest(struct Test a){}
"
device = first(cl.devices())
ctx = cl.Context(device)
prg = cl.Program(ctx, source = test_source)
queue = cl.CmdQueue(ctx)
cl.build!(prg)
structkernel = cl.Kernel(prg, "structest")
astruct = ((1f0, 2f0, 3f0, 0f0), Int32(0), 22f0)

sizeof(astruct)
# == 24 exactly the same as what sizeof(struct Test a) in the kernel returns

astruct_boxed = Ref(astruct)
cl.@check cl.api.clSetKernelArg(structkernel.id, cl.cl_uint(0), sizeof(astruct), astruct_boxed)
```

So I have confirmed, that the size of `sizeof(astruct)` and the size in the kernel match, but I still get an `CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE` error. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Passing kernel arguments which are other than simple types is perhaps not part of the official capabilities. I've seen it work on some platforms, but it depends on struct alignment being the same, which often isn't the case. I'd suggest passing individual parameters or if a have a bunch of the same type, a vector.

Comment: Well, that's why I made sure that the alignment is the same ;)

Comment: Btw, this is for https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CLArrays.jl, which transpiles Julia code to OpenCL, and handling arbitrary structs is a crucial part of this - and it has been working pretty well on most architectures so far. And by well I mean it has been a nightmare until I finally got it working for all GPU OpenCL implementation that i have access to :P

Comment: The standard doesn't specifically mention passing aggregate types as by-value kernel arguments as far as I can tell, so it's not clear to me if not supporting it is a bug in the implementation or if you're just expecting unspecified behaviour. I'd file a bug report with AMD and see what they say. As a workaround, you could copy structs into an OpenCL memory buffer and pass them by reference?